# Rabbitmq server not picking value from rabbitmq.conf file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, rabbitmq, messaging

I am using the latest version of RabbitMQ for clustering. I was setting some custom values and parameters on nodes via rabbitmq.conf file by placing it inside the /etc/rabbitmq directory and then restarting `rabbitmq-server`, but when I verify it through `rabbitmqctl` environment it still shows the default values

Current rabbitmq.conf content:

```
vm_memory_high_watermark.relative = 0.7
disk_free_limit.relative = 1.0
cluster_partition_handling = autoheal
loopback_users = none
```

Currently cluster is a three node cluster on bare ec2 machines

Answer (score 0):

I found it's answer myself. Actually the `start_err` log helped, if the current directory has old format `config` file present, it will not activate the values passed in new format `.conf` configuration file. On rebooting the services it doesn't throw any error. 
Sanity while upgrade, a good habit to keep!